# Is recursion the only way to solve Tree questions

Tags: recursion, tree

I recently started learning about Tree data structure and have been solving questions on that topic. For all the questions I have solved so far, I haven't been able to come up with any approach other than recursion (iterative solution in some cases, but even those could be coded up more quickly with recursion). So I was wondering if all tree related questions have only recursive approach and if not could someone share some questions that need to be solved with non-recursive methods?

Comment: A common iterative technique for processing trees involves using Stack or Queue data structures

Comment: Typically solutions that use a breadth-first traversal do not use recursion.